# Disabled DateTime field is marked as required in MVC4 page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

One of my models contains a property which looks like this

```
private Nullable<DateTime> myDate;

[Display(Name = "My Date")]
[Editable(false)]
// [DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime MyDate
{
    get { return this.myDate?? new DateTime(1, 1, 1); }
    set { this.myDate = value; }
}
```

`// [DataType(DataType.Date)]` is commented out because it's a leftover from some experiments I made.

In my "edit" view I render the property like this

```
// input.noborder { border: 0 none; }
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyDate, new { @readonly = true, @class = "noborder" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InvoiceDate)
```

I did not create an `EditorTemplate` for DateTime type. Finally, in the scripts of the same view, I attach `jQuery Datepicker`

```
var $dpMyDate = $('[name=MyDate]');
$dpMyDate.datepicker();
```

I basically want to render a read-only `datepicker` (next step would be to implement more scripts which would enable it if some conditions are met).

Everything seems to work but upon clicking the "save" button, validation tells me that the field is required, but I expected it not to be, since I didn't put the `[Required]` attribute in the class. Also (but this might just be me assuming too much) it feels weird that a readonly input field would be required (how is one supposed to fill it?)

I don't see anything wrong with the code, am I missing something ?

Comment: I actually recalled the ASP.NET MVC treats non-nullable types in a special way. In particular, during the model binding phase, it needs to put _something_ there. Since it's non-nullable it usually picks the default value for that type. As a result, unintuitively, it _doesn't_ validate a `[Required]` non-nullable type (because it just checks if it's not null... and of course it's not null!). Any chance you can post the exact error message and the HTTP request with the relevant form data?

Comment: I just see the standard `.ValidationMessageFor()` output telling me `MyDate is required` (no POST is performed since validation doesn't pass). Maybe the type simply doesn't have a "default" for MVC to fill it up with (and the fact I'm initializing it in the getter isn't considered)?

Comment: Ah of course. You fail at that javascript validation. Then indeed it's just the issue I/maxs87 mentioned which is that the property the ASP.NET MVC actually cares about, `MyDate`, is a non-nullable type. ASP.NET MVC automatically generates javascript which marks it as required. You probably don't want an `EditorFor()` because I _believe_ ASP.NET MVC will attach the javascript validation to that `input` element. Instead, use `DisplayFor()` and perhaps your own DisplayTemplate + a corresponding hidden `input` element which is actually submitted to the server.

Comment: Please put that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading the comments it looks like you failed at the javascript validation that ASP.NET MVC adds. The issue is that, while your private field is nullable, the property is non-nullable (`DateTime` is a struct). ASP.NET MVC binds to the property and concludes that it is "Required" even though it's not marked as `[Required]`.

As a result, ASP.NET MVC will generate javascript as if it were marked as a `[Required]` property. In particular, you used an `EditorFor()` and so the javascript ASP.NET MVC injects will treat it as required. Since it's a readonly form element *I believe* the javascript will complain.

The way to get around this is to use a `DisplayFor()` which doesn't have that javascript attached.

Note that if you have a *nullable* property that is `[Required]` but you don't want it to be editable, you'll actually need to do something extra in addition to using `DisplayFor()`--you'll need to submit *something* in the HTTP request that ASP.NET MVC knows how to model bind. The most popular option is an `<input>` element with `type=hidden`. Because the user has absolute control over the HTTP request he sends to the server, you would probably want to ignore the submitted value to prevent "overposting".

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Change this

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyDate, new { @readonly = true, @class = "noborder" })
```

to

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MyDate, new { @readonly = true, @class = "noborder" })
```

And remove `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InvoiceDate)` it's no need.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because your date not Nullable.
Try to define it like

```
public DateTime? MyDate
```